# Stack Overflow keeps logging me out every few minutes

Tags: bug, login

It's been happening for the last few days. Whenever I open Stack Overflow, it's logged out.

I log in and browse for a while and then close the tab. When I re-open it after a few minutes, e.g. 20 minutes, it asks me to log in again.

Comment: Possibly related: [Getting logged out of Stack Overflow due to RSS feeds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424244/208273)

Comment: This sort of bug gets reported every now and then, and no one has ever managed to reproduce it consistently other than the people reporting it.  Any information you can provide to narrow it down would help.

Comment: Do you have any plugins enabled? Anything that could be interfering with your cookies? Or anything that could be blocking something on your network?

Comment: For starters, what browser on what platform, incl. versions and editions (if any)?

Comment: And how do you login. Local account, federated through Google or Github...